# Why doesn't java.lang.Thread class have a constructor which takes only a ThreadGroup in?

Tags: java, multithreading, constructor

java.lang.Thread class has a constructor which takes in only a string parameter as the thread name. It has a constructor which takes in only a Runnable target. But it also has a default constructor. This means the name or the Runnable target is not mandatory.

But this is a bit different when it comes to creating a Thread with a ThreadGroup. There is no constructor which takes only a ThreadGroup in. At least the name or the Runnable target goes in with the ThreadGroup.

Is there any reason for java.lang.Thread class to not have a constructor which only takes a ThreadGroup in?

Comment: I think you cannot add a Thread to a ThreadGroup after creating it. The ThreadGroup has to be given when the creating the Thread.

Comment: It's hard to answer a question like "why did the authors decide not to do...", without being the authors. But in any case, it's easy to do so by using one of the other constructors: `new Thread(myThreadGroup, (Runnable)null)`.

Comment: In the past, sub classing Thread as more accepted than it is today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to create a `Thread` with only a `ThreadGroup` parameter, you can use the [`Thread(ThreadGroup, Runnable)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread-java.lang.ThreadGroup-java.lang.Runnable-) constructor with a null `Runnable`, which will have the same effect. I.e.,

```
t = new Thread(threadGroup, (Runnable)null);
```

(The cast is necessary to disambiguate it from the `Thread(ThreadGroup, String)` constructor.)

There's no absolute reason why `Thread` couldn't have a constructor taking only a `ThreadGroup`, but there are already *eight* constructors. Each one of them is a complexity and burden on testing and documentation and trying to figure out which one you're invoking. The ninth constructor would struggle to justify its existence. In fact, given how rarely used `ThreadGroup`s are, it would be no loss if there were fewer overloads, not more.